# C++ Data structure Big O

Tags: c++, data-structures, big-o

Hello in Data strucrure Big O does this code count as (n ^ 2 + N ^ 2) neglecting that we take the biggest, or  just N ^ 2 because the DM's are in the same loop ? thank you .

```
   int sum1,sum2;
   for (int i = 0 ;i < n;i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0 ; j < n; j++)
        {
          sum1 = i + j; //DM
          sum2 = i ;    //DM
        }
   }
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Either you are high, or I am.

Comment: What is "N"? What is a "DM"? The algorithm as you have it is O(n^2), and it performs exactly 2 n^2 assignments and n^2 additions. (That says nothing about the *runtime* of the program, since a clever compiler might figure out the result and just store that.)

Comment: I am not high n represent an unknown loop number ... if you don't know data structure please don't answer and DM means Data Move since in data structure they are divided into DM and DC data comparison

Comment: Not directly relevant, but smart compiler would optimize it to `O(1)`. Did you mean `+=`?

Comment: @zch as far as i know changing values is considered a DM

Comment: @user1948105: The problem is that DM is not a common abbreviation. In general try to avoid abbreviations unless you know for a fact that they are well known by most people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is both O(N^2) and O(2*N^2). It is also O(1/2 * N^2) and O(1000 * N^2). They are all equivalent due to the way big-O notation is [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition).

Comment: Yes i do know that but i just wanted to know how do we look at it before we simplify it as N ^ 2 + N ^ 2 or just N ^ 2 because both dm are in the same loop not because the big O ignore constants

Comment: There are numerous ways to look at it before simplifying. I could say that I know everything inside the loop is constant time and just count that as '1', or I could count number of assignments, or comparisons, or integer operations. The point is for big-O, it doesn't matter which of these I choose. Big-O is not designed for precise performance comparisons so it does not make sense to talk about O(2N^2) vs O(N^2). For real world performance comparisons the best way is usually to just benchmark the code.

Answer (score 3):

The ordo notation only considers the fastest-growing part of the computational complexity, if there are additions and subtractions going on. Constants are also not noted. So this code essentially runs in `O[2 * (n ^ 2)]` (without optimization - it's probably better to say *its time complexity* is this and that) which is then just `O(n ^ 2)`.

Comment: Thank you so the exact running time would be 2 * n  ^ 2 ?

Comment: @user1948105 Who knows the exact running time?